# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose', on import

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(5)
y = range(5,11)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelrisling/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/michaelrisling/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/michaelrisling/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 17, in <module>
    verbose = matplotlib.verbose
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose'
```

Answer (score 2):

I also meet the same problem, I think this problem is the version of MatplotLib, I solve this problem by using version 2.12.

Comment: **Yes.** Matplotlib 2.2.0 significantly [broke backward compatibility](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10716) and should effectively be considered dead on arrival. With any luck, a new point release will be issued shortly.